# Azure Storage Copy between Accounts - In what order?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Working on copying Azure Storage Account blobs one one subscription to another.  Does anyone know if files (blobs) are copied in sequence?  For example:

- Folder1

  - File1
  - File2
  - File3
- Folder2

  - File1
  - File2
  - File3
    .
    .
    .

Are the above copied in the order shown?  I am using "Az Storage Blob Copy" command.

Thanks

Comment: yes, this command is copied in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is copied in sequence. But it can not copy folder. The command will take folder as blob, and then it will throw out error.

The bulk copy is like this:

`az storage blob copy start-batch --account-key xxx --account-name xxx --destination-container xxx --source-account-name xxx --source-account-key xxx --source-container xxx`

And this is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Thanks Bowman.  I kid of felt that it should be copy in sequence.  During my test run, with real storage account, it seems to be in sequence but somehow it started to jump around after some time.  Don't understand why.

BTW.  I am using "copy start" as opposed to "copy start-batch"